# modern way to get City,State, Country from latitude and longitude

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I'm building a React app and I need to display the City and State associated with the user's location we find from their latitude and longitude.

I've seen quite a few, albeit old (3+ years), posts describing a process involving using Reverse Geocoding from google, and then parsing our data looking for the address_component administratvie_are_level_1.

For example: [Getting street,city and country by reverse geocoding using google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173242/getting-street-city-and-country-by-reverse-geocoding-using-google)

This seems like a lot of extra working to find the City, State from lat long. I'm wondering if there is a more modern and sleek way to get this operation done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting street,city and country by reverse geocoding using google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173242/getting-street-city-and-country-by-reverse-geocoding-using-google)

Comment: @ecg8 I've seen and am using something similar was hoping there was a way to avoid extra data mutations, perhaps not. Thanks